# Scroll to negative part of a div in a smaller div

Tags: html

A bigger div with image (in a smaller one) has a absolute position with negative top and left, so the wanted part is shown at startup. In de smaller div are scrollbars but you can not scroll to the part left and above, only to right and below.

How can I position the scrollbars a little to the right and lower at startup so I can also scroll to the part left and up?

Part of the code to illustrate:

```
<div  id="container" style="width:300px; height:300px; position:relative; overflow:auto;">
 <div  id="content" style="position:absolute; top:-300px; left:-200px;">
  <img src="image.jpg" width="850" height="600"></img> 
 </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RVYtR/1/

Comment: it seems like you should have the content as top 0 and left 0 but when displaying it on startup, scroll to the correct position for the container div. You will need js for that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it only with HTML or CSS. You will need to make use of JavaScript.
I did it using [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/):

```
$('#container').scrollTop('300').scrollLeft('200');
```

Living example: http://jsfiddle.net/RVYtR/3/